# Express"with each other" or "amongst themselve"

Tags: translation

I'd like to express the idea that the members of a group perform a multi-party action, e.g., conversing, amongst themselves.　E.g., "My co-workers use English when they talk amongst themselves".

The best I can do right now is:

我同事互相交谈用英文。

But I imagine there's a lot of work to be done here, both in expressing the notion of "amongst themselves" and translating the "when X, Y" subordinate structure.

Comment: The English idea of `amongst` could just simply be omitted here without losing clarity.

Answer (score 1):

"My co-workers use English when they talk amongst themselves".
我的同事们之间用英语聊天儿。

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one way to express this sentence in Chinese

1.

> "My co-workers talk among themselves" = "我的同事們私下交談"
>
> "My co-workers  (use English) (when) they talk among themselves" = "我的同事們私下交談(時)(使用英語)"
>
> "**我的同事們私下交談時(都是)使用英語**"  - *Add 都是 (always) to make it more clear*

2.

> "My co-workers talk among themselves" = "我的同事們私下交談"
>
> "(when) my co-workers talk among themselves, (they use English)  " = "(當)我的同事們私下交談(時), (他們使用英語)"
>
> "**(當)我的同事們私下交談(時), (他們都是使用英語)**" - *Add 都是 (always) to make it more clear*

Edit:

dan wrote:

> *私下交談 denotes those informal circumstances, which doesn't well address the sense of talk among themselves.*

I replied:

> *'私下交談' means 'talk privately' implying 'without including people outside of their circle. May be I can change '我的同事們私下交談' to '我的同事們在他們之間交談' to make the translation more direct, but that would be quite wordy*

If I decided to use the more direct translation, the sentences would become:

**"我的同事們(在他們之間交談時)都是使用英語"**

**"(當)我的同事們(在他們之間交談時), 他們都是使用英語"**

But it can be rephrased to make less wordy:

"**我的同事們之間的交談都是用英語**" (the conversations between my co-workers are all in English)

Comment: 私下交談 denotes those informal circumstances, which doesn't well address the sense of *talk among themselves*.

Comment: @dan '私下交談' means 'talk privately' implying 'without including people outside of their circle. May be I can change '我的同事們私下交談' to '我的同事們在他們之間交談'to make the translation more direct, but that would be quite wordy

Comment: Wouldn’t 聊天(兒) be a better word than 交談?

Answer (score 0):

> "My co-workers use English when they talk amongst themselves".

I will interpret it as: 我们同事之间交谈使用英文. Or 同事之间交谈我们使用英文.

Among themselves(coworkers): 同事之间;

when they talk amongst themselves: 我们同事之间交谈

My co-workers use English:  (我的同事们)使用英文

You can add 相互，but the meaning stays unchanged. 我们同事之间相互交谈使用英文 is fine too.